# CSS overflow Property/Update

Tags: css, sass

Is there a new update for CSS? For some reason, I noticed that my website and several others that usually has `overflow : auto` now has a visible scroll? I though it was my browser( Chrome ) turns out, its with firefox and safari as well.

Comment: The overflow:auto property is supposed to show scroll only if the text overflows

Comment: I assume you are on Mac for Safari, it could be that text overflows, or you had your setting changed in MacOS to always show scrollbars.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Well you guys should checkout websites that had an overflow : auto like twitter.com, apple.com and now they have a visible scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Default behavior when a mouse is present with mac os]

So i found the actual cause of this. When the computer registers a mouse, it automatically adds scroll bars as default. This can be configured in the settings > general > show scroll bars option